# Visual Studio 2022 не видит / не устанавливает пакет .NET 7. В целом, установка проходит успешно, но в настройках проекта отсутствует (см. скрины)

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2022, .net-7

[скан командной строки, .NET7 установлен](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pbLp.png)
[Visual Studio 2022. Проект -> Свойства проекта -> Приложение. Нет пункта .NET7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amHmG.png)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хочу использовать C# 11, для этого нужен пакет .NET 7.x. Мои действия: 1) Установил этот пакет (успешно, без ошибок); 2) Захожу в свойства проекта изменить платформу на NET7, но в выпадающем списке этого пункта нет (скрины приложены к вопросу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. создать проект с платформой NET7 не получалось в Visual Studio, то создал его через cmd командой "dotnet new console -o MyApp -f net7.0".
Открыл его в в Visual Studio, вышла ошибка NETSDK1045: текущий пакет SDK для .NET не поддерживает в качестве целевого объекта "более новую версию".

Гуглим её, попадаем на страницу Микрософта, где среди прочего указано:

- проверить архитектуру x86 или x64;
- проверить версию Visual Studio 2022.

В моём случае было необходимо обновить Visual Studio 2022 с 17.0 до 17.4